I successfully deployed a smart contract using the Solana playground, which gives an IDL.json, but my frontend require a IDL.js
Recently, I made a simple smart contract using the Solana playground which gave me the IDL.json.
But the problem arises when I try to use the IDL.json in my frontend as in the latest tutorials they use IDL.js, which is quite different from the JSON.
Is there a way I can use my IDL.json.

I think you may have the two files mixed up.
The IDL.json describes the program, the accounts and the instructions in your anchor program. You can use it to get a general idea of the program. This file is usually located in the target/idl/program_name.json
You then have your typescript types located in the target/types/program_name.ts. In your TS client, these make it possible to get type inference and use the instructions from your program.
import type { ProgramTypes } from "./idl/program_name";
import * as programIDL from "./idl/program_name.json";

program = new Program<ProgramTypes>(
  programIDL as unknown as ProgramTypes,
  provider
);

ref: https://solana.com/docs/programs/anchor/idl

I believe we get these when we build and deploy on our local machine.
But I am using the Solana playground(beta.solpg.io), which just gives us the idl.json.
Is there a way I can make this work?

I am unsure as to whether you can export the type definition file. You can confirm this by asking in the GH repo

Thanks for the help, everyone.
The issues have been resolved.here
